Continuous image of interval in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is not null measure
It is known that given $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, the graph of this function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Lebesgue measure $0$ (follows from uniform continuity of $f$ and rectangles parallel to the $x, y$ axis).
It is also known that if $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is Lipschitz, then $f[a, b]$ is Lebesgue measure $0$.
I suspect with the wide variety of continuous functions that given an arbitrary $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ continuous, then $f[a, b]$ is not necessarily Lebesgue measure $0$. Does anyone have a counterexample?

Consider any space filling curve.

Thanks, for some reason I thought space filling curves were only an approximation, but I guess they are literally space filling.

Besides space-filling curves, there are even injective continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ whose image has positive measure.

@bof Can you give me a term to look up or where I can read more about this?

By the Denjoy–Riesz theorem (a.k.a. the Moore–Kline theorem), every compact totally disconnected set in $\mathbb R^2$ is contained in a Jordan arc. A compact totally disconnected set can have positive measure.

Ok, as Ben pointed out, any space filling curve will do. For some reason I thought space filling curves were only an approximation, but there exist continuous surjections $f: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]^2$

Space filling curves are generally constructed using a sequence of approximations ${f_0, f_1, f_2, \dots }$ such that $f_n \to f$. Although the image of each $f_n$ is measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, this is not true of $f$.

Yeah, I had never studied them that carefully. I have seen the images of the successive approximations of the Peano curve being constructed and figured they weren't literally space filling.
